# Initialising member to class function causes 'self' used in method call error

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, initialization

I have a class attribute that points to one of the class functions. However when I try to initialize this variable with one of the functions, I get the following error:

> 'self' used in method call before all stored properties are initialized.

I'm able to initialize any other variable to those functions, but the error makes it sound like I'm calling the function even though I'm not.

```swift
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class BeatMaker {

    // iPhone 7 and up use beat function, iPhone 6s use beatFallback
    let hapticFunction: () -> ()
    let impactGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.init(style: .heavy)

    init(supportsImpactGenerator: Bool) {
        // error 1: 'self' used in method call 'beat' before all stored properties are initialized
        // error 2: 'self' used in method call 'beatFallback' before all stored properties are initialized
        self.hapticFunction = (supportsImpactGenerator) ? beat : beatFallback
    }

    private func beat() {
        impactGenerator.impactOccurred()
    }

    private func beatFallback() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520)
    }

    func makeABeat() {
        hapticFunction()
    }
}
```

In this specific case I want to make use of the Taptic Engine and simulate a click through the `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator`. The iPhone 6s doesn't support this engine, so I want to call a fallback function that produces a similar effect.

I also tried initializing the variable on the spot:

```swift
// this works
var hapticFunction: (BeatMaker) -> () -> () = beat

init(supportsImpactGenerator: Bool) {
    if !supportsImpactGenerator {
        // error: Cannot assign value of type '() -> ()' to type '(BeatMaker) -> () -> ()'
        self.hapticFunction = beatFallback

        // produces same error
        self.hapticFunction = beatFallback.self
    }
}
```

I know that I could make everything static or put everything out of the class, but this *feels* like it should work yet it doesn't. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Setting the type of type of `hapticFunction` to an optional seems to work, but this doesn't make any sense to me. What's the difference?

```swift
// this works
var hapticFunction: (() -> ())?

init(supportsImpactGenerator: Bool) {
    self.hapticFunction = (supportsImpactGenerator) ? beat : beatFallback
}
```

Comment: You can simply declare `hapticFunction` as optional and use `convenience init` instead.

Comment: @koropok Huh, didn't even have to be a `convenience init` to work, just setting `hapticFunction` to type `(()->())?` works

Comment: @Kamran How is the error self explanatory? The error says I'm calling the function, it's not saying that I'm accessing an instance method

Comment: @Kamran Please also see my edit, because if I'm not allowed to access instance methods my "solution" feels like it shouldn't work

Comment: well with `convenience init` you can init your stored properties first with `self.init()` first, thus allowing you to assign your functions to `hapticFunction `.

Comment: `self` is an instance of the same type to access its own methods. When you use `self` in the initializer to access a method(e.g, beat, beatFallback), compiler verifies that its stored properties are initialized first so it fails because `hapticFunction` is not yet initialized. When you declared `hapticFunction` as an `Optional` property, it means it is initialized to `nil` by default so when you are accessing instance methods in the initializer, instance properties initialization condition is fulfilled hence compiler does not throw any `error`.

Comment: @Kamran oh wow, I see. Thanks for the clarification, this caused a lot more headaches than it should have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be better to not use a `Bool`, but rather a nested `Enum`, which is also more extendible if you wanna add some other modes of haptic feedback later on.

I have a generalized solution for a generalized problem of your question. So either you do:

```swift
public class FunctionOwner {

    private let mode: Mode

    public init(`do` mode: Mode = .default) {
        self.mode = mode
    }
}


public extension FunctionOwner {

    enum Mode {
        case foo, bar
    }

    func fooOrBar() {
        switch mode {
        case .foo: foo()
        case .bar: bar()
        }
    }
}

private extension FunctionOwner {
    func foo() {
        print("doing foo")
    }

    func bar() {
        print("doing bar")
    }
}

public extension FunctionOwner.Mode {
    static var `default`: FunctionOwner.Mode {
        return .foo
    }
}

// USAGE
FunctionOwner(do: .bar).fooOrBar() // prints "doing foo"
FunctionOwner(do: .foo).fooOrBar() // prints "doing bar"
```

Or if you for some reason do want to keep the stored `Mode`, you can do this (might be relevant for your actual question on how you do a workaround of referencing `self` in the init.):

```swift
public class FunctionOwner {

    private let _function: (FunctionOwner) -> Void

    public init(`do` mode: Mode = .default) {
        _function = { functionOwner in
            switch mode {
            case .foo: functionOwner.foo()
            case .bar: functionOwner.bar()
            }
        }
    }
}

public extension FunctionOwner {

    enum Mode {
        case foo, bar
    }

    func fooOrBar() {
        _function(self)
    }
}

// The rest of the code is the same as the example above
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two method to fix this

You can:

Give `hapticFunction` a initial value like `{}`

or fix like:

```
class BeatMaker {

    let impactGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.init(style: .heavy)
    let supportsImpactGenerator: Bool

    init(supportsImpactGenerator: Bool) {
        self.supportsImpactGenerator = supportsImpactGenerator
    }

    private func beat() {
        if supportsImpactGenerator {
            impactGenerator.impactOccurred()
        } else {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520)
        }
    }

    func makeABeat() {
        beat()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I like the first solution a lot :)